# Expected Write condition is not working in script

Tags: powershell

The cert is removed as expected if the condition is met, but the text "The cert is being removed"  is not showing up.

Please advise

```
$pc = '.'
$cert_store = 'My'
write "The is the cert store we are working with : $cert_store"
$store = New-Object system.security.cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store ("My","LocalMachine") #LocalMachine could also be LocalUser
$store.Open('ReadWrite')
write "opening the store for editing"
## Find all certs that have an Issuer of old CA
$certs = $store.Certificates | Where { $_.Issuer -eq 'CN=DomainRootCA, DC=Corporate, DC=Local' }
if ($certs -ne $null)
{
    ## Remove all the certs it finds
    $certs | foreach { $store.Remove($_) | write "The cert is being removed" }
}
```

Comment: What if you change this line $certs | foreach { $store.Remove($_) | write "The cert is being removed" } to this line $certs | foreach { $store.Remove($_) ;write "The cert is being removed" } (meaning changing the pipe to the semicolon)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @DVT It worked perfectly!

Comment: @DVT post an answer

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I posted the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this was due to there is nothing output from Remove. If you change the pipe (|) to semicolon (;), it works.

```
$pc = '.'
$cert_store = 'My'
write "The is the cert store we are working with : $cert_store"
$store = New-Object system.security.cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store ("My","LocalMachine") #LocalMachine could also be LocalUser
$store.Open('ReadWrite')
write "opening the store for editing"
## Find all certs that have an Issuer of old CA
$certs = $store.Certificates | Where { $_.Issuer -eq 'CN=DomainRootCA, DC=Corporate, DC=Local' }
if ($certs -ne $null)
{
    ## Remove all the certs it finds
    $certs | foreach { $store.Remove($_) ; write "The cert is being removed" }
}
```